# Can I use a MSI laptop with the video card removed?

Tags: graphics-card, headless

I have a MSI gx640, I thought the only thing wrong with it was a bad video card. The screen always stays black, an external monitor does not work either.

I have a ssd with ubuntu and ssh configured, when I put this ssd in the MSI laptop, it does not seem to boot (never gets an IP address from dhcp server). The lights on the laptop light up when it powers on. I have tried this both with the video card installed, and with it removed. When the card is installed, it is clearly getting warm, without, it doesn't get warm at all.

Is there likely something else wrong with this computer, or does the system rely on the video card for more than driving the monitor(s)? Is there a way to use this computer headless, without buying a new graphics card?